# MS Access VBA hide or delete row from form but not table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use a form to edit a table. What I want to do is once a checkbox in the form is ticked or a field is filled out with some text I want to hide / remove this row from the form view but not delete the row from the table itself. Is this possible with VBA?

Comment: Use a suitable field / column -- `SELECT FROM table WHERE modifieddate >=date()` / `is null`

Comment: This is confusing. What kind of form is your form? Is it a datasheet? How does the system know, when you check a box or fill out a field, what row to hide..?

Comment: Sounds like you should base your form on a query instead of a table, and in the query, only bring up those rows where MyCheckBoxColumn = False or MyTextColumn NOT LIKE "*MyFilterText*".

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to resort to VBA to accomplish this.

Base the form on a query that filters out those records with the appropriate field filled in. Then when you next call the form those records checked will not appear.

It is good practice to have all forms based on queries (apparently)